# When they "buck barley bags", what does it mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "buck" mean in the following sentence?

> Well, God knows he don't need any brains to **buck** barley bags.

Comment: Please cite the source of this and any quote you use here, both for proper attribution, and so that  people can dind additional context. Please list the title, and the author or publication., If possible, include a link to the source you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buck)

> **4 b :** to move or load (heavy or cumbersome objects) especially with mechanical equipment

Comment: Is it dialectical?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Not dialectical, but I believe it is mostly specific to farming, so it might count as industry jargon. I've heard of bucking hay bales, and not much else. I'd guess a lot of urban-dwelling native speakers don't even know this meaning of the word.

Comment: It's not dialectal/regional as far as I know, but it might be an American usage; I can't see it in Oxford's UK English dictionaries although it is in the US Merriam-Webster.